# how to modify url name for a particular website

Tags: php, html, url, dns, web

I want to know how url name is modified. There is a website called tcyonline.com but it also has one other url which is institute.tcyonline.com and it changes to other names also accordingly. I want to know how it is done. I mean everytime are they purchasing a different url or there is some way to do it. Please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

When you purchase a domain name let's say apple.com, you are essentially buying a domain name itself. You are then able to create as much directories as you want. In the terminology-wise, there is a hierarchy in DNS names, in our example, you are buying a second-level domain and can make as much of third-levels as you wish.

Check this svg illustration

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name#/media/File:DNS-names-ru.svg

Usually, your domain name provider offers you these options in the administration, where you can create 3rd-level names. Some servers even have this set by default so when you buy a domain + hosting, the folder system is linked - meaning when you log onto the server via ftp, you can create folder at the same level as the main /www/ folder and your new one becomes the 3rd-level name (before the "dot" of your 2nd level name)

Answer (score 0):

For a standard www.example.com. domain. The www part is the name of the machine that belongs to the example.com. domain.

If you also have a server named banana, you can have banana.example.com.

You can also have another domain underneath example.com. tomato.example.com. The machine names under that domain could be www.tomato.example.com, or equally, soup.tomato.example.com.

The part that you purchase from a domain provider is the example.com. part. You can do pretty much anything you want with the rest. Once you have the domain name you have automatic rights to all properly formatted machine names and subdomains underneath it.

If you wanted to use SSL certificates you would need to purchase certificates for each of those names though, as each is (possibly) a discrete, unique location on the internet.

This is also no the URL, it is simply the hostname. A Url consists of the protocol () a hostname (www.example.com) and a file path / file name (/docs/index.html)

(this is a simplified explanation, as with all things it can get hugely more complicated and nuanced)